# Is it possible to reuse a layout in Kotlin Anko

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, anko

I read that the most benefit of using Anko is its reusability. But i could't find its exact example.

Currently in the new Android layout system, the boiler plate is like below:

```
DrawerLayout (with some setup)
   CoordinatorLayout (with some setup)
      AppBarLayout (with some setup)
         ToolBar
      <The Main Content>
   NavigationView (with header inflated)
```

From the layout structure above, only `<The Main Content>` is varry. And 
in many cases those ceremonial setup duplicated almost in every activity.

So here with Anko im thinking if there is a reusable solution about that issue. Im not expecting it will be reusable for general purpose layout, but et least i can minimize the ceremonial code in the project. Maybe i need something like:

```
class MainUI: AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
  override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>): View{
     return with(ui) {
        myCustomRootLayout {
           //here is what <The Main Content> will be
        }
     }
  }
}
```

From the code above im expecting `myCustomRootLayout` will do all the ceremonial setup for the root layout such as (DrawerLayout, CoordinatorLayout etc etc).

Is that possible?

**EDIT**
So i think my question is: **How to make a custom component which can host other component**

Answer (score 4):

One way to reuse the code is to simply extract `myCustomRootLayout` into a extension method like so:

```
class MainUI: AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>): View {
        return with(ui) {
            myCustomRootLayout {
               recyclerView()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun <T> AnkoContext<T>.myCustomRootLayout(customize: AnkoContext<T>.() -> Unit = {}): View {
    return relativeLayout {
        button("Hello")
        textView("myFriend")
        customize()
    }
}
```

However as [stated in the documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko#ankocomponent):

> Although you can use the DSL directly (in `onCreate()` or everywhere
>   else), without creating any extra classes, it is often convenient to
>   have UI in the separate class. If you use the provided AnkoComponent
>   interface, you also you get a DSL layout preview feature for free.

It seems to be a good idea to extract the reusable piece into separate `AnkoComponent`:

```
class MainUI : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>): View {
        return with(ui) {
            MyCustomRootLayout<MainActivity>({
                recyclerView()
            }).createView(ui)
        }
    }
}


class MyCustomRootLayout<T : Context>(val customize: AnkoContext<T>.() -> Unit = {}) : AnkoComponent<T> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<T>) = with(ui) {
        relativeLayout {
            button("Hello")
            textView("myFriend")
            customize()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. yes i understand about that. but could find example of how to make custom component which is a container of other component. See my code, `myCustomRootLayout` should contains `DrawerLayout, CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout` etc etc, but also should host another component `<The Main Content>`. So in the future i can use them like:  `myCustomRootLayout {  recyclerView() }` (adding a recycler view inside it)

Comment: @ktutnik both `myCustomRootLayout` extension method and the `MyCustomRootLayout` class accept a delegate that is invoked after setting up the components elements. This delegate can be used to add custom child elements i.e. `recyclerView()`

Comment: Im consern about the position of the inserted child. Is there require some effort to put the children as the children of CoordinatorLayout vs the root view?

Comment: @ktutnik I have an almost same issue. Have you found out a way to insert the Custom View as a child to another layout?

Comment: @SuhairZain: sorry still can't find out the way.

Answer (score 3):

I actually found a way to do this, took me a while to figure it out.

I have a very basic test layout here, the content gets added to a 
`RelativeLayout`.

The key here is to add your custom layout in a delegated `AnkoContext` that delegates to the immediate parent (the `RelativeLayout` in my case).

```
abstract class BaseAnkoComponent<T> : AnkoComponent<T> {

    companion object {
        val TOOLBAR_ID = View.generateViewId()
        val COLLAPSING_ID = View.generateViewId()
        val COORDINATOR_ID = View.generateViewId()
        val APPBAR_ID = View.generateViewId()
        val CONTENT_ID = View.generateViewId()
    }

    abstract fun <T> AnkoContext<T>.content(ui: AnkoContext<T>): View?

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<T>) = with(ui) {
        coordinatorLayout {
            id = COORDINATOR_ID
            lparams(matchParent, matchParent)
            appBarLayout(R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay) {
                id = APPBAR_ID
                lparams(matchParent, wrapContent)
                fitsSystemWindows = true
                collapsingToolbarLayout {
                    id = COLLAPSING_ID
                    val collapsingToolbarLayoutParams = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent)
                    collapsingToolbarLayoutParams.scrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL or AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS
                    layoutParams = collapsingToolbarLayoutParams
                    isTitleEnabled = false
                    toolbar {
                        id = TOOLBAR_ID
                        val toolbarLayoutParams = CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent, dimenAttr(R.attr.actionBarSize))
                        toolbarLayoutParams.collapseMode = CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.COLLAPSE_MODE_PIN
                        layoutParams = toolbarLayoutParams
                        minimumHeight = dimenAttr(R.attr.actionBarSize)
                        background = ColorDrawable(colorAttr(R.attr.colorPrimary))
                        popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme_PopupOverlay
                    }
                }
            }
            with(AnkoContext.createDelegate(relativeLayout {
                id = CONTENT_ID
                val relativeLayoutParams = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent)
                relativeLayoutParams.behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
                layoutParams = relativeLayoutParams
            })) {
                content(ui)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can extend the `BaseAnkoComponent` and build your content in the same way with Anko DSL.

```
class FooActivityUi : BaseAnkoComponent<FooActivity>() {
  override fun <T> AnkoContext<T>.content(): View? {
    return verticalLayout {
      lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)
      button("Hello")
      textView("myFriend")
    }
  }
}
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this but I have not found it. Kinda new to Kotlin and Anko.