# How to make universal AppBar with Anko DSL?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, anko

I'm trying to make a toolbar that I can insert into other Anko components. Here is an example of what I am going for:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        MainUI().setContentView(this)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = find(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }
}

class MainUI : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {
        coordinatorLayout {
            fitsSystemWindows = true
            lparams {
                width = matchParent
                height = matchParent
            }
            ToolbarUI().createView(ui).lparams { width = matchParent }
            recyclerView {...}.lparams {
                width = matchParent
                height = matchParent
                behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
            }
        }
    }
}

class ToolbarUI : AnkoComponent<AppCompatActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<AppCompatActivity>) = with(ui) {
        appBarLayout {
            ...
            toolbar {
                setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                id = R.id.toolbar
                title = resources.getString(R.string.main_activity)
                ...
            }.lparams {
                width = matchParent
                height = wrapContent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way I could use this same AppBarLayout elsewhere with much less code. But I am getting this:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: View is already set: org.jetbrains.anko.design._AppBarLayout`

Anyone could help me with the correct way to implement this?

Comment: Are you using xml file or dynamically creating elements?

Comment: Dynamicly with Anko DSL, as the code shows.

Comment: I think you have stripped out some methods, can you pull at least invoking method in your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the only code I stripped was very specific to user input events. This error occurs before those events can be fired.

Comment: If this is the case, I cant figure out where did you assign layout to your activity.

Comment: In the main activity.  `MainUI().setContentView(this).  Anko DSL creates the view dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145518/discussion-between-phito-and-chandil03).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it with ViewManager based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40147360/create-a-custom-view-viewgroup-class-in-anko-dsl?rq=1).

Here is the new code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        MainUI().setContentView(this)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = find(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }
}

class MainUI : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {
        coordinatorLayout {
            fitsSystemWindows = true
            lparams {
                width = matchParent
                height = matchParent
            }
            toolbarUI(resources.getString(R.string.main_activity)).lparams { width = matchParent }
            recyclerView {...}.lparams {
                width = matchParent
                height = matchParent
                behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
            }
        }
    }

    fun ViewManager.toolbarUI(activity: String) = appBarLayout {
        toolbar {
            setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            id = R.id.toolbar
            title = activity
        }.lparams {
            width = matchParent
            height = wrapContent
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ToolbarUI().createView(ui)` creates view on the same AnkoContext, on `ui`, which is created with `setContentView = true` by default.
You can try using another AnkoContext, which is not going to attach view to Activity: `ToolbarUI().createView(AnkoContextImpl(activity, this /* parent ViewGroup */, true))`.